# Contrast enhancement on UInt16 data type to set the maximum value greater than 255 with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, rendering

I have loaded a raster layer with gdal DAAS plugin and would like to set a contrast-enhanced rendering, but my pixel data are in the range [536, 1747] and I cannot achieve modifying the max value of contrast enhancement accordingly.

I set this max via `myEnhancement.setMaximumValue(1747)`
but looking at the value in QGIS or via `myEnhancement.maximumValue()` highlights that this value is always 255. Setting with a value lower than 255 is OK.

I checked my raster dataType via `provider.dataType(1)`, it returned UInt16
Setting the minimum value at 536 is working fine... But not the maximum (even with this value)

Any idea on how to get the correct max beyond this 255 limit?

Here is the code portion for contrast enhancement :

```py
ds = dal.OpenEx('daas:https:...', open_options=["PIXEL_ENCODING=RAW"])
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadRaster(5000, 5000, 977, 240, 977, 240)
block = QgsRasterBlock(Qgis.UInt16, 977,240)
block.setData(array)
extent = ...
crs = ...
params = {
    'EXTENT': extent,
    'TARGET_CRS': crs,
    'PIXEL_SIZE': 1,
    'NUMBER': 1,
    'OUTPUT_TYPE': 2,
    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
}
r = processing.run('qgis:createconstantrasterlayer', params)['OUTPUT']
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(r, 'temp', 'gdal')
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()
provider.setEditable(True)
provider.writeBlock(block, 1, 0, 0)
provider.setEditable(False)
myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement() 
myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum,True)
myEnhancement.setMinimumValue(536)
myEnhancement.setMaximumValue(1747)
renderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(provider,2)
renderer.setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default `DataType` of `QgsContrastEnhancement` is `Byte` ([Reference](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsContrastEnhancement.html#a1a8753c291fd555c978579900c27a4ee)). Specify `DataType` during instantiation.

Without specifying `DataType`:

```
e = QgsContrastEnhancement() # Qgis.Byte by default
e.setMaximumValue(1000)
print(e.maximumValue())

# OUT: 
# 255
```

With specifying `DataType`:

```
e = QgsContrastEnhancement(Qgis.UInt16)
e.setMaximumValue(1000)
print(e.maximumValue())

# OUT: 
# 1000
```